# Hypergeometric function plot

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I can't plot this??!! if you can check this thank you.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Integrate[1/Sqrt[a (x)^(-3 b + 2) + k], x]



Clear["Global`*"]
k = 0.002; a = 0.68; b = 1;
Plot[1/Sqrt[k]x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(2 - 3 b), 1 + 1/(2 - 3 b), -((x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k)] Sqrt[1 + (x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k], {x, 1, 100}]
```

Comment: Because: `(x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(2 - 3 b), 
     1 + 1/(2 - 3 b), -((a^(2 - 3 b) a)/k)] Sqrt[
     1 + (x^(2 - 3 \[Gamma]) a)/k])/Sqrt[k + x^(2 - 3 \[Gamma]) a] /. 
 b -> 1` ? and `\[Gamma]` not defined ?

Comment: Gamma is nearly one.

Comment: I just also checked and edited the formula, please see it agian

Comment: Plot[Evaluate[Simplify[g[x] /. {k -> 1/500, b -> 1, a -> 7/10}]], {x, 
  1, 12}, PlotRange -> {-70, 70}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"T", "a/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(0\)]\)"}]

Comment: look again with is the solution please

Comment: The Hypergeometric function is infinite for `b = 1`.  Try with other values of `b`.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to see what's happening is the following.

```
$Version

"13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"
```

We define

```
k = 0.002;
a = 0.68;
```

and then inspect

```
1/Sqrt[k] x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(2 - 3 b), 
   1 + 1/(2 - 3 b), -((x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k)] Sqrt[
   1 + (x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k] /. b -> 1
```

> `ComplexInfinity`

You can do an animation for some values of `b` if you want to graphically inspect what's going on. You can see that the animation gets red at some point.

```
animation = 
 Animate[
  Plot[1/Sqrt[k] x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(2 - 3 b), 
     1 + 1/(2 - 3 b), -((x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k)] Sqrt[
     1 + (x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k], {x, 1, 100}], {b, 0, 2}]
```

[image: animation]